# Perl - count by client# loop

Tags: perl

I have the following sub that will count the number of purchases for each client.  It used to be only/always 4 categories, and the script below would be sufficient.

Client list:

- alpha01
- alpha02
- alpha03
- alpha04
- bravo01
- bravo02
- bravo03
- bravo04

Since the list has grown to >4, I need help to modify the script.
I want the script to be flexible.  Instead of fixing the "MYClientNo" to a certain number/value, the script can continue to run in a loop until it finds the last/biggest number available (just a thought), then only it will stop and return the value.

For example "alpha" could go up to 06, "bravo" to 22.  But I don't foresee it grow pass 100 any time soon.  Can anyone help?

```
sub GetCountMyClient {
    my @Line1 = @_;
    my @Count = (0, 0, 0, 0);
    foreach $myclient (@Line1) {
        my @MYClient       = split(/\s+/, $myclient);
        my @MYClientOutput = split(/:/, $MYClient[4]);
        #print $MYClientOutput[0]. "\n";
        my $MYClientNo     = substr($MYClientOutput[0], -2);
        #print $MYClientNo . "\n";
        if($MYClientNo eq "01") {
            $Count[0]+= 1;
        } elsif($MYClientNo eq "02") {
            $Count[1]+= 1;
        } elsif($MYClientNo eq "03") {
            $Count[2]+= 1;
        } elsif($MYClientNo eq "04") {
            $Count[3]+= 1;
        }
    }
    return @Count;
}
```

PS: I tried my best to ident the codes, it looks correct in the textbox, but just not in preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash (`%count`), where the hash keys are the client numbers, and the hash values are the counts. Alternatively, you could use an array with the client number as the array index.

```
sub GetCountMyClient {
    my @Line1 = @_;
    my %count;

    foreach $myclient (@Line1) {
        my @MYClient       = split(/\s+/, $myclient);
        my @MYClientOutput = split(/:/, $MYClient[4]);
        #print $MYClientOutput[0]. "\n";
        my $MYClientNo     = substr($MYClientOutput[0], -2);
        #print $MYClientNo . "\n";
        $count{$MYClientNo}++;
    }
    return %count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find `count_by` from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtilsBy) helps you here.

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( count_by );

my %count = count_by { $_ =~ m/(\d+)$/ } @client_names;
```

Presuming the `@client_names` array contains just the names of the clients, this will return a hash giving the count of how many end with each kind of digit string.